# How to reinstall python after removing /usr/lib/python* files?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, virtualenv

I ran into an issue where I had two versions of python installed on my WSL distro running Ubuntu 22.04.3 through VSCode. I used apt-get remove python3 followed by apt-get purge python3 as well as apt-get remove python3.10 followed by apt-get purge python3.10. I was doing this while I was in a virtual environment. When I reinstalled, I continued to run into an issue where I could not use pip to install to my virtual environment. So I uninstalled again using the same method and noticed there were still two directories in /usr/lib/python* so I used rm -rf to remove those. Now when I try to reinstall I get the following error:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python3-minimal
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
python3-minimal
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 125 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.12-1\~22.04.3) ...
Could not find platform independent libraries \<prefix\>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to \<prefix\>\[:\<exec_prefix\>\]
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = (not set)
PYTHONPATH = (not set)
program name = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
isolated = 0
environment = 0
user site = 1
import site = 0
sys.\_base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3.10'
sys.prefix = '/usr'
sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
sys.path = \[
'/usr/lib/python310.zip',
'/usr/lib/python3.10',
'/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
\]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007fb86b043000 (most recent call first):
\<no Python frame\>
dpkg: error processing package python3.10-minimal (--configure):
installed python3.10-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3.10-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried running apt-get autoremove, apt-get clean,apt-get upgrade -f --fix-missing, setting PYTHONHOME="/usr/local" in my .bashrc. I've completely removed all of my virtual environments and I still can't seem to figure out how to fix this error. Please Help!!

Comment: this probably belongs on askubuntu, but you may need to get and install python from deb if you've removed libraries needed by `apt` .. it's generally also best to re-create virtialenvs when needed (at least `pip freeze` will show their contents)

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll ask there. What do you mean install python from deb?

Comment: ah, get the deb directly from ubuntu and install it with dpkg if apt is broken